# Oracle restrict rows based on category

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a DB structure like below:

```
id  value  category
1   val1     6
2   val2     6
3   val3     5
4   val4     7
5   val5     8
5   val5     5
```

I need to display the result based on the number of category after sorting. Suppose if value of category is 2 then results should be:

```
id  value  category
    3   val3     5
    5   val5     5
    1   val1     6
    2   val2     6
```

This is a dynamic table and after some time records with category 6 may get deleted and now if category is 2, we need to display:

```
id  value  category
3   val3     5
5   val5     5
4   val4     7
```

After research one solution I found is using rownum:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CATEGORY IN
(SELECT CATEGORY FROM 
(SELECT ROWNUM ROWNUMBER, CATEGORY FROM 
(SELECT CATEGORY FROM TABLE GROUP BY CATEGORY ORDER BY CATEGORY)) WHERE ROWNUMBER >= 2)
```

But I know this is not very efficient. Is there any more optimized way of doing it ?

Comment: "Suppose if value of category is 2 then results should be..." Why? There is no category of 2 and how does 2 relate to getting categories of 5 and 6? Or is it to do with the number of rows in the category? Or getting a number of categories? Why if category 6 is deleted should you return category 7 and not category 8? Are you sure the sample code you've posted gives the results you are expecting because it does not give either of the outputs you have posted? ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c9345edff3dc92054a49b112bba42b14))

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to select `n` categories with the highest counts.  If so:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by cnt desc, category desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by category) cnt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```